# Could not find or load main class in both Tomcat and Workspace

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, struts, metadata

I have been tasked with adding some new features in a project I worked on a while back.  It's been given some new features since I last worked on it, and the development environment has changed.  I'm having a lot of troubles bringing my environment up to date with all the dependencies and external folders.

After solving a host of problems, when running the **Tomcat 7 Server** in **Eclipse** I was coming across a message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Path\To\Workspace\.metadata\plugins\cont
```

I tried deleted the **Tomcat Server** and then recreating it with the same settings, as well as deleting my `.metadata` folder from the workspace.  Now I can't even get Tomcat to configure right:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\ApacheSoftwareFoundation\apache-tomcat-7.0.26.
```

Why isn't this working?  It worked before I added a couple of needed subdirectories but I'm stumped now.

Comment: Please (re-)read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on writing good questions.  There's almost no context here for anybody to help you.  This is about equivalent to calling your car repair shop and telling them over the phone that your "check engine" light is on and expecting them to tell you what's wrong without seeing the car.

Comment: @JimGarrison it's either a simple fix with a simple and common mistake on my part or it's more complicated and no amount of context will get the answer.  I'm hoping it's the former but if not I don't expect a resolution through SO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just was searching for the same problem in Eclipse("Could not find or load main class").

It turned out in my case that there was an extra space in launch configuration arguments tab. (In Java EE perspective go to Servers, click on Tomcat server, in Overview window select 'Open launch configuration' and then go to Arguments tab). Arguments are listed as

```
-Dx.y.z=1 -Da.b.c=2 ...
```

and so on, but as the dialog itself is small and arguments go across multiple lines it's not always clear where there is a space and where there is a new line. In my case it was

```
-Dx.y.z =1 -Da.b.c=2 ...
```

(there is a space before =1) which confused Tomcat and I got "Could not find or load main class" error.

It's not necessarily your case but somebody else can come across this and find it to be the answer.

Comment: I had a similar problem where a copy/paste error had removed a - in front of one of the arguments. This answer told me exactly where I should be looking, and careful examination of the arguments revealed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the .metadata folder eclipse saves it's internal configuration, so you should not affect it manually. The errors give you the clue to get that resource it's looking is not accessible what ever it exists or not. Try to find it manually to check if it exists, then try to make it accessible, fix the path, change permissions, etc. May be you have classpath issue, who knows.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse I added a Tomcat Server and it was working fine. I stopped the server to alter the settings. Specifically, I checked the 'Enable security' box. When I tried to start, I got this error. So I unchecked the box and tried to restart the server - same error. This thread led me to check the launch configuration VM arguments. Sure enough, Eclipse had not handled the checkbox (and unchecking it) correctly. The VM arguments had two places where it repeated strings without quotes. Check there to see if it has been malformed.